# Issue in installing NodeJS in docker container

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, dockerfile

We’ve created a new ASP.Net core + Angular application. We are deploying the application in AKS Container via Azure CI/CD process. We’ve added the below commands in the docker file (Container) to install Node in the container during runtime.

```
        RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y wget && \
        apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
        wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - && \
        apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
```

We’re using the URL - https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x to install nodeJs in the docker container during container build process. On Devops server, this script gets executed internally & tries to connect to http://deb.debian.org/ site.

In my organization, firewall restrictions are in place to prevent any http call from Devops server. This is preventing the script from getting executed.

*Below is the log from DevOps*

```
apt-get update Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (199.232.106.132), connection timed out Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:80:
```

Our security team is not allowing to open port 80 for accessing the http url as this will lead to security risk.

Do we need to make any changes in the docker file or any settings? We would like to know if we're following the correct steps and also if there is any workaround to overcome this http call.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you use a container you can use `FROM` multiple times. So do not use wget. Use instead FROM Node:xxx

Comment: As i've already explained, i'm using  ASP.Net core + Angular application. Can I use both .Net image and Node image?

Answer (score 1):

Using a generice base image has some overheads as well. Like running each command inside dockerfile creates an extra layer and your final image size would be huge. You can read more about best practices to write dockerfile [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/). Just like Flo mentioned in comment, most feasible solution is to use a node:x.x.x base image that has all required packages already installed. Here is the sample dockerfile that you can use.

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Reference:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-node-js-application-with-docker

Comment: Yeah, only, use `yarn` because it's faster than `npm`

Comment: Thank you for your response. We do not want custom image to be created. We are fine with adding an extra layer to our image. Is there any way in calling it using https instead of http url?

Comment: To reiterate, the https url - https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x tries to connect to http://deb.debian.org/ site internally. Is there any way in calling the url using https instead of http? Http calls are restricted in our organization for security reasons.